# Add a IF (Background Color) conditional to Copyto Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So Tanaike was kind enough to make a Copyto function for me previously, which basically took a snapshot of a spreadsheet I had and copied it to a new location without bringing along the respective formulas of each cell:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Master Menu')
      .addItem('Archive Report', 'Archiver')
      .addToUi();
}

function Archiver() {
  var spreadsheetId = "File_ID"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  var destFolderId = "File_ID";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

  // Copy each sheet in the source Spreadsheet by removing the formulas as the temporal sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().map(function(sheet, i) {
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();

   src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});


    return dstSheet;
  });

  // Copy the source Spreadsheet.
  var destination = ss.copy(ss.getName() + " - " + new Date().toLocaleString());

  // Delete the temporal sheets in the source Spreadsheet.
  tempSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {ss.deleteSheet(sheet)});

  // Delete the original sheets from the copied Spreadsheet and rename the copied sheets.
  destination.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf("_temp") == -1) {
      destination.deleteSheet(sheet);
    } else {
      sheet.setName(sheetName.slice(0, -5));
    }
  });

  // Move file to the destination folder.
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(destination.getId());
  DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId).addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
}
```

I am grateful for this function, but there is one last thing I would like to do with this if possible: I would like to make it so that ONLY cells that are highlighted green ("#0D7813") have their respective formulas removed (contents only), while all other cells have their formulas preserved, when the sheet containing them is copied over. I tried my hand at making this working but I don't know how to make a boolean statement for this, here was my attempt:

```
// Copy each sheet in the source Spreadsheet by removing the formulas as the temporal sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().map(function(sheet, i) {
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
    var backgrounds = tempSheets.getDataRange().getBackgrounds()

    if(backgrounds === "#0D7813"){
    src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
    }
    else{
      src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: false});
    }
    return dstSheet;
```

I don't know how to make a boolean for individual cells for the process since it seems to be copying the whole sheet. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here you go Lamb, thank you for all your help by they thusfar :) :

[image: Original Master]

[image: script I'm using]

[image: Resulting copy]

Here is a link to a sample of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NcS22owCLKOrx5ZU1zyuBEJPgHZfmtn55oh6R_uUkMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a link to a sample of the sheet it references: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10vX8cT1d8OCRXsB9rWtdSvVv4HTN3jCuo-96ZnNp2g4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please bear in mind that [getBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgrounds()) returns a two-dimensional array of color codes, not just one value. So the condition `backgrounds === "#0D7813"` can never return `true`. You have to check each cell individually.

In this case, I would (1) copy all the spreadsheet as it is, with formulas, and after that (2) loop through each cell (with content) of each sheet, and remove the formula if the background color is the specified one.

So you could change this:

```
  // Copy each sheet in the source Spreadsheet by removing the formulas as the temporal sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().map(function(sheet, i) {
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();

   src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});


    return dstSheet;
  });

  // Copy the source Spreadsheet.
  var destination = ss.copy(ss.getName() + " - " + new Date().toLocaleString());

  // Delete the temporal sheets in the source Spreadsheet.
  tempSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {ss.deleteSheet(sheet)});

  // Delete the original sheets from the copied Spreadsheet and rename the copied sheets.
  destination.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf("_temp") == -1) {
      destination.deleteSheet(sheet);
    } else {
      sheet.setName(sheetName.slice(0, -5));
    }
  });
```

To this:

```
  // Copy all the spreadsheet (formulas included)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var destination = ss.copy(ss.getName() + " - " + new Date().toLocaleString());
  var backgroundColor = "#0d7813"; // The background color you want to check for  
  destination.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) { // Iterating through each sheet in the destination    
    var backgrounds = sheet.getDataRange().getBackgrounds(); // Getting 2-dimensional array with background colors for each cell in the sheet    
    for (var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) { // Iterating through each row
      var rowBackgrounds = backgrounds[i];      
      for (var j = 0; j < rowBackgrounds.length; j++) { // Iterating through each cell for that specific row
        var cellBackground = rowBackgrounds[j];        
        if (cellBackground === backgroundColor) { // Checking if the cell background color is the same as the specified one          
          var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
          cell.copyTo(cell, {contentsOnly: true}); // Removing formulas from the cell
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Check the comments I added in the code to see what the script is doing line by line.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203211/discussion-on-answer-by-iamblichus-add-a-if-background-color-conditional-to-co).